# c# SOAP web service can not deserialize complex object references in the response xml

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

I try to consume a SOAP service and it works fine for some functions. But when I get a more complex result with object references in the response xml the serialization fails with the error: "Error in Xml Document at 2,991" and the inner exception is : The referenced element with ID '2' was not found in the document. As you see in the following XML-Response he found allready one reference, but the 2nd one to the object couldn't be found.

This is the incoming XML-Response

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:NS1="urn:LagerVerwaltungIntf-ILagerVerwaltung">
      <NS2:TLagerortResult id="1" xmlns:NS2="urn:LagerVerwaltungIntf" xsi:type="NS2:TLagerortResult">
        <Status xsi:type="xsd:int">1</Status>
        <Msg xsi:type="xsd:string">
        </Msg>
        <Lagerort href="#2" />
      </NS2:TLagerortResult>
      <NS2:Lagerort id="2" xsi:type="NS2:TLagerort">
        <LagerCode xsi:type="xsd:string">L1001001</LagerCode>
        <LagerName xsi:type="xsd:string">Lager 1</LagerName>
        <LagerTyp xsi:type="xsd:string">LagerPlatz</LagerTyp>
        <LagerGemeinde xsi:type="xsd:string">Test</LagerGemeinde>
        <LagerBetrieb xsi:type="xsd:string">Gut Test</LagerBetrieb>
      </NS2:Lagerort>
      <return href="#1" />
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Here the specified object from the Reference.cs

```
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.8.3761.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:LagerVerwaltungIntf")]
    public partial class TLagerort {

        private string lagerCodeField;
        
        private string lagerNameField;
        
        private string lagerTypField;
        
        private string lagerGemeindeField;
        
        private string lagerBetriebField;
        
         /// <remarks/>
        public string LagerCode {
            get {
                return this.lagerCodeField;
            }
            set {
                this.lagerCodeField = value;
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        public string LagerName {
            get {
                return this.lagerNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.lagerNameField = value;
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        public string LagerTyp {
            get {
                return this.lagerTypField;
            }
            set {
                this.lagerTypField = value;
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        public string LagerGemeinde {
            get {
                return this.lagerGemeindeField;
            }
            set {
                this.lagerGemeindeField = value;
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        public string LagerBetrieb {
            get {
                return this.lagerBetriebField;
            }
            set {
                this.lagerBetriebField = value;
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapIncludeAttribute(typeof(TKisteResult))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapIncludeAttribute(typeof(TCodesResult))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapIncludeAttribute(typeof(TLagerortResult))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapIncludeAttribute(typeof(TPartieResult))]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.8.3761.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:LagerVerwaltungIntf")]
    public partial class TResult {
        
        private int statusField;
        
        private string msgField;
        
        /// <remarks/>
        public int Status {
            get {
                return this.statusField;
            }
            set {
                this.statusField = value;
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        public string Msg {
            get {
                return this.msgField;
            }
            set {
                this.msgField = value;
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.8.3761.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:LagerVerwaltungIntf")]
    public partial class TCodesResult : TResult {
        
        private string[] codesField;
        
        /// <remarks/>
        public string[] Codes {
            get {
                return this.codesField;
            }
            set {
                this.codesField = value;
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.8.3761.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:LagerVerwaltungIntf")]
    [System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.SoapType(XmlNamespace = "urn:LagerVerwaltungIntf")]
    public partial class TLagerortResult : TResult {

        private TLagerort lagerortField;
        
        /// <remarks/>
        public TLagerort Lagerort {
            get {
                return this.lagerortField;
            }
            set {
                this.lagerortField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

[link to the WSDL](https://easyupload.io/rs30yw)

Is there any specific setting or something else that the service can deserialize the object?

Comment: I don't think that error is a serialization error. Can you show some context around how you are calling this operation and what you are doing with the result?

Comment: Maybe you should deserialize it as an array, not an object?

Comment: Do you have the schemas?  The response XML may not meet schema.  The schema may require ID=2 but the response may not contain the value.

Comment: It is a serialization exception, because it started with: "Error in Xml Document at 2,991" and the inner esception is : The referenced element with ID '2' was not found in the document.

Comment: If schema is not correct (doesn't match xml) serialization will have errors.